# How to call "class method" from outside class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've got some code in JavaScript and I'm looking to trigger a `ViewModel` method using a keyboard shortcut. What is the correct syntax? Here's my code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode==27){
        ViewModel.escapePressed();
    }
}, true);

function ViewModel() {
    this.escapePressed=function(){
        // Code
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use that style of class, then you must first make an instance of it.

```
var a_view_model = new ViewModel();
a_view_model.escapePressed();
```

… but if you just want to have a static method, then you probably shouldn't be using a constructor function in the first place

```
var view_model = {
    escapePressed: function () { };
}
```

and:

```
view_mode.escapePressed();
```

Comment: Or put it on the prototype without instantiating a new object, and calling off the prototype. Not sure his use case, but agreed on not using a constructor for this though, just throwing another idea out there.